# How to attach menu control with panel in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

When we place a menu control in a form it attaches to the form at the top. Suppose there is a panel in my form and I want to attach a menu control to it rather than the form. How could i do it? Please help me to achieve it.

thanks

Comment: Stop and think about what you're asking, and how to ask it, before you ask it. Your question is barely comprehensible.

Comment: I agree, I am not sure I understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just place the menu strip inside a panel. Nothing fancy as by default the Dock property is set to "Top".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Click on your menu strip.  Cut it. **Ctrl+X**.  Click on your panel. Paste it. **Ctrl+V**.

The menu will persist it's docked property, which is defaulted to the Top of the parent control.

Comment: Oops sorry.. didnt see your answer. One small correction though - Paste = Ctrl+V :)

Comment: Yes, but note that Form has a `MainMenuStrip` property. Not all functionality (Merging ?) might work when it's on a Panel. Probably not a problem, but Test it well.